# Search for rows that contain a string from another table list

Tags: mysql

so I have 2 tables. chat_table, bad_words_table. Now I need a query that searches all chats that have bad words.

```
chat_table(id, user, chat) - contains all chats

bad_words_table(id, word) - contains a list of offensive words.
```

Now I need some sort of query that takes all chats from chat_table WHERE the chat CONTAINS any of the words FROM bad_words_table;

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `JOIN` between the two tables such that `chat LIKE %bad_word%`. A chat may contain multiple bad words; we can get unique chats only using `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM chat_table AS c
JOIN bad_words_table AS bw 
  ON c.chat LIKE CONCAT('%',bw.word,'%')
```

For larger tables, I would recommend to use [Full Text Searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead, as `LIKE %..%` will not be able to use any Indexing.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by Full Text Searching?